# validate input from the function in c

Tags: function, validation, loops, double

[i want the  input and validation features for “top_speed” and
“horsepower” in this fuction: double get_positive_value() , but i am not getting it resolved.Additionally, the top speed or horsepower
of the car must not be less than or equal to zero. If an invalid top speed or horsepower is inputted, repeat the
input prompt until a valid value is entered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AiUs.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow SE.  Be sure to take the tour at https://stackoverflow.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your function definition at the top of the page has one argument:

```
double get_positive_value(float num);
```

Which does not match the argument list of where you actually have your code:

```
double get_positive_value()    // this is missing "float num" argument
{
    //code
}
```

---

Secondly, once you originally scan for input in your "main" function you then call the function "get_positive_value()" right of way:

```
scanf("%f",&top_speed);
top_speed = get_positive_value(top_speed);
```

That function will always display an "error" message and it then executes another "scanf" in the do-while loop.

```
double get_positive_value()
{
    do{
        printf("error\n");
        scanf("%f", &num);
        ...
      }
    while(num<=0);

    return num;
}
```

This will require at least 2 inputs for each variable "top_speed/year/horsepower".

I'm not sure what you're not getting "resolved" but if my answer seems to follow what's wrong just change your function to

```
double get_positive_value(double value)
{
    while(value <= 0){
        printf("error\n");
        scanf("%f", &value);
        ...
      }

    return value;
}
```

This matches your original function declaration including arguments and it only goes through the loop in your function once if the original input was greater than 0.

I hope that helps